# PowerMock WhenNew rewrite

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am updating to JDK17 and it seems PowerMock is not compatible, as a result one of my test classes is not working and the code that I am trying to replace is :

`whenNew(A::class.java).withAnyArguments().thenAnswer {invocations ->  ClassB( arg1 , invocation.getArguemnt(0) )  }`

I tried Mockito and Mockk but couldn't achieve the proper result.

I tried mockedConstruction and also Mockito.mockConstruction, maybe I am doing it wrong. Anyone knows a good alternative for it?